# Are Google Cloud preemptible VMs less likely to be interrupted mid-task during the night hours in each respective region?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to run a cluster on Google Compute Engine preemptible nodes. I'm wondering if it's more advantageous to pick a region for the cluster nodes where it's night when I typically run my jobs.

Are there any statistics on where it's most advantageous to run a cluster of preemptible nodes by the local start time of jobs?

(There is an old related question here: [Which Google Compute Engine Server is least likely to preempt my vms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829622/which-google-compute-engine-server-is-least-likely-to-preempt-my-vms) , but it does not address my question specifically about usage statistics by time of day.)

Comment: currently there is no usage statistics on what time of the day it will be advantageous on picking a region for the Preemptible Compute Engine. you can also check the documentation on [Preemptible instance limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#limitations)

Comment: I'll be providing my comment above for greater visibility of the community.

Comment: What if everyone else has the same idea?

Comment: If everyone has the same idea, the hypothetical graph would look flat. On the other hand, Google might achieve better usage of its compute resources if they provided such a graph, cause then people would shift their workloads towards underutilized regions at the right times

Answer (score 1):

To address your question, currently there is no usage statistics on what time of the day it will be best or advantageous to run the Preemptible VMs/Spot VMs, in terms of picking up a region and zone keep in mind that Generally, communication within regions will always be cheaper and faster than communication across different regions. And some point in time, your instances might experience an unexpected failure. To mitigate the effects of these possible events, you should duplicate important systems in multiple zones and regions.

for further information you can also check the documentation on [Preemptible instance/Spot VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/spot), [Location selection tips](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#tips) and [General best practices for Spot VMs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/compute/google-cloud-spot-vm-use-cases-and-best-practices).